# Are there any de-novo genome assembly programs for HADOOP?

Tags: bioinformatics

I have access to a small (approx 20 nodes) cluster that has HADOOP running on it, and I need to do some de-novo genome assembly. I'd like to ask is anyone knows of any program that can do this on a HADOOP cluster. Cloud based stuff is not an option right now, unfortunately, so I need something that I can deploy on our cluster locally. Thx in advance.

Comment: You can try CONTRAIL and CLOUDBRUSH...